# ModisDownload - doubts when using MRT tool

Tags: r, modis, ndvi, modis-reprojection-tool

I am using the incredible [MODISDownload](http://www.r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload) function from the [rts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/index.html) package in R to download NDVI data on vegetation index in Africa.

I have two questions.

I am using the latest version of the package available on github, and I download and reproject the images with the following code (which works beautifully):

```
ModisDownload(x=x,h=c(19),v=c(5), version = '006', dates=c('2000.01.01', '2000.02.28'),
              MRTpath=path,mosaic=F,proj=T, bands_subset="1 0 0 0 0 0", 
              proj_type="GEO",proj_params="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0",
              datum="WGS84",pixel_size=0.001)
```

where `x = "MOD13Q1"` and `path` is the path to my MRT/bin folder. I choose only band 1 because I am interested in the NDVI index, which is the first band. I choose `proj_type = "GEO"` as I want the projection on longitude/latitude format.

I am not very sure about my choice of the `proj_params` and `pixel_size` parameter. For the former, I mimic what is automatically set if I do the reprojection using the MRT GUI interface, but I am not sure whether that is correct.

For the `pixel_size`, though, I am completely lost. It is clear that the smallest its values, the higher the resolution of the outcome tif file. However, the higher will the its size on disk. Thus, I was wondering whether someone would know how can I calculate an 'optimal' pixel size for the 250m resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check reference manual. See [Apendix C](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/mrt41_usermanual_032811.pdf) to know about projection parameters. They are used for datum conversions:

[image]

If you want a 250m pixel size, use a meter projected CRS like WGS 84 UTM zone *X n/s* and set pixel size = 250. Working with a lat/long projection isn't possible to get a 250m pixel size for all locations.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!